# Classifying a singularity

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose that $g(z)$ is an entire function with a zero of order $k$ at $z=0$.  The question is to classify the singularity of the function $\frac{\sin g(z)}{g(z)}$ at $z=0$.  I want to say that, since $$\lim_{z \to 0} \frac{\sin g(z)}{g(z)}=\lim_{z \to 0} \frac{g'(z)\cos g(z)}{g'(z)}=\lim_{z \to 0} \cos g(z)=1,$$ the function $\frac{\cos g(z)}{g(z)}$ is bounded in a neighborhood of $0$, and so the singularity is removable.

1. Is this reasoning sound?
2. Is there a reason I should have expected the singularity to be removable (rather than a pole) at the outset?

Comment: Yes, this reasoning is sound. The justification of this, and perhaps a more natural approach, is to write $\sin g$ in terms of a power series in $g$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function $u \mapsto \frac{\sin u}{u}$ has a removable singularity at $0$ ( see also http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sinc_function).  Hence the function $\text{sinc}( g(z)) = \frac{\sin g(z)}{g(z)}$ is entire.

Since $g(0)=0$, and $0$ is not a critical point of $\text{sinc}$, we conclude that $\text{sinc}(g(z))$ has a zero of same order $k$ at $0$.